How to create 4 flex box containers per row
I am simply looking to move the 8 flex box items I have (name: products-box) to 4 per row. Here is what I have so far:


*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
}
header{
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.products-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.products-box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightpink;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
.main-container{
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.nav-sidebar{
    min-width: 150px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.inner-text{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: auto;
}
<header>
    <span class="inner-text">Header</span>
</header>
<div class="main-container">
    <aside class="nav-sidebar" id="nav-container">
        <span class="inner-text">Sidebar</span>
    </aside>
    <div class="products-container">
        <div class="products-box">
            Item1
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item2
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item3
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item4
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item5
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item6
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item7
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item8
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



I am trying to get the flexbox labeled products-box to be 4 per row, and be even if not.

Try tweaking your css a little bit:

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.products-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr; /* Changed from repeat(4, 1fr) to 1fr */
  gap: 1em;
  align-self: start;
}

.products-box {
  aspect-ratio: auto; /* Remove fixed aspect ratio to allow full width */
  background-color: lightpink;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.nav-sidebar {
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.inner-text {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
}


Hope that helps :)

For displaying products, I prefer a grid. The snippet below demonstrates a grid with a fixed number of columns.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.products-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
  align-self: start;
}

.products-box {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-color: lightpink;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.nav-sidebar {
  min-width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1em;
}

.inner-text {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 24px;
}
<header>
  <span class="inner-text">Header</span>
</header>
<div class="main-container">
    <aside class="nav-sidebar" id="nav-container">
        <span class="inner-text">Sidebar</span>
    </aside>
    <div class="products-container">
        <div class="products-box">
            Item1
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item2
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item3
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item4
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item5
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item6
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item7
        </div>
        <div class="products-box">
            Item8
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



The potential problem with this is that the size of each product box varies greatly depending on the screen width. If you want to keep the size of the product boxes more consistent and instead vary the number of products in each row, you could use auto-fit.
.products-container {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(12em, 1fr));
}

Or you could make it responsive using media queries:
/* two columns on phones */
.products-container {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

/* three columns on tablets */
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .products-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

/* four columns on desktops */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .products-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}


Thank you very much! This is what is was looking for. If I wanted to change the boxes to an entire row instead, how could I adjust?

Try tweaking the css a little bit to achieve that, like this:

.products-container {
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
.products-box {
aspect-ratio: auto; /* Adjust or remove fixed aspect ratio */
}

Try that and let me know if it helps :)

@ThomasEddingtonIII - I have updated my answer to mention media queries as well. I imagine you will need to vary the number of columns depending on the screen width, so you can choose either media queries or the auto-fit method.

Since a parent container/row has a width of 100%.
To have 4 product-boxes per row, each product-box should occupy 25% of the its parent element.
Check it out below code:


    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    body{
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    header{
        height: 80px;
        display: flex;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    .products-container{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .products-box{
        width: 25%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: lightpink;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 200px;
    }
    .main-container{
        display: flex;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
    .nav-sidebar{
        min-width: 150px;
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
    .inner-text{
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 24px;
        margin: auto;
    }
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <span class="inner-text">Header</span>
    </header>
    <div class="main-container">
        <aside class="nav-sidebar" id="nav-container">
            <span class="inner-text">Sidebar</span>
        </aside>
        <div class="products-container">
            <div class="products-box">
                Item1
            </div>
            <div class="products-box">
                Item2
            </div>
            <div class="products-box">
                Item3
            </div>
            <div class="products-box">
                Item4
            </div>
            <div class="products-box">
                Item5
            </div>
            <div class="products-box">
                Item6
            </div>
            <div class="products-box">
                Item7
            </div>
            <div class="products-box">
                Item8
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



